# Count items in arrays cross 100's of thousands of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails app with a Postgres database that has an Artists table with a jsonb `genres` column.

There are hundreds of thousands of rows.

Each genre column in the row has an array like `["rock", "indie", "seen live", "alternative", "indie rock"]` with different genres.

What I want to do is output a count of each genre in JSON across all the rows.

Something like: `{"rock": 532, "power metal": 328, "indie": 862}`

Is there a way to efficiently do that?

**Update...here's what I've got at the moment...**

```
genres = Artist.all.pluck(:genres).flatten.delete_if &:empty?
output = Hash[genres.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
final = output.sort_by{|k,v| v}.to_h
```

Output is a hash instead of JSON, which is fine.

But already feels pretty slow, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I’d probably use a new table (or two) to store the counts in reasonable batches.

Comment: What is efficient for you? What have you try?

Comment: What I would do is extract the data from the JSON `group by` and `count` and then create the JSON  you need

Comment: I would say there is a much better way to do it. Use a proper normalization table to store genres and use a join table to join genres and artists. Then you can simply get the desired result by querying the join table and grouping by `genre_id`. This seems like yet another case where using JSON/array data types is just crappy db design.

Comment: Not the answer you're probably looking for, so I'll leave it as a comment instead: When I run up against things that seem slow using Rails queries I build a view directly in the DB and add a model in Rails to access it. Rails operations will probably not be as efficient as the DB as that is what the DB is designed to do. Postgres has tools for working with JSON columns directly.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Just realized your column in the DB is an array. Let me consider that...

Comment: @Beartech I don't think there really is a way to group by JSON/array values in postgres in this way - anyways you would need to pull every genres from every row in the artists table to even get the complete list of genres - which in itself is a huge problem.

Comment: Per my second comment: at first I thought he was querying a JSON column which has it's own internal operators that can be used in a Rails query. But since he's querying an array column it's actually quite a bit easier. I would bet that a single query that does all the work on the DB side will be faster and is possible. Working on it right now.

Comment: @Beartech it could just as well be a json/jsonb column that happens to consist of just an array.

Answer (score 0):

On re-reading your question you state that the column IS a JSONb type. So the answer below will not work since you need to first get the array from the jsonb column. This should work better:

```
output = Artist.connection.select_all('select genre, count (genre) from (select id, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(genres) as genre from artists) as foo group by genre;')

=> #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x00007f8ef20df448 @columns=["genre", "count"], @rows=[["\"rock\"", 5], ["\"blues\"", 5], ["\"seen live\"", 3], ["\"alternative\"", 3]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={"genre"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Jsonb:0x00007f8eeef5d500 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>, "count"=>#<ActiveModel::Type::Integer:0x00007f8eeeb4c060 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil, @range=-2147483648...2147483648>}> 

output.rows.to_h

=> {"\"rock\""=>5, "\"blues\""=>5, "\"seen live\""=>3, "\"alternative\""=>3}
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you can change the DB to normalize it, go for it. An anonymous array in a jsonb column is just going to be painful going forward. If you need to use this answer I would at least think about adding a view to the DB so that you can get the genre count as a table that has a corresponding model in rails (that you can just create in your model definitions).

Original answer when I thought your column was a regular array column type in Postgres.

Here is a SQL way to do it in Rails:

```
genre_count = Artist.connection.select_all('SELECT
                                   UNNEST(genres),
                                   COUNT (UNNEST(genres))
                                  FROM
                                   artists
                                  GROUP BY
                                   UNNEST(genres);')
```

You can then use the method of your choice to turn a much smaller dataset into JSON.

I am not familiar enough with `UNNEST` know why I can't alias it like any other column to make it prettier. But it works.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30597/21/0

Comment: I think you intended to use `select_all` and not `find_by_sql`. `find_by_sql` will create model instances which in this case will give a pretty useless result as the columns don't have aliases so you won't be able to access anything. `select_all` gives you the raw result object.

Comment: I'll take your word for it as I have nothing to test it against, just doing this in my head from the fiddle.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Comment: Something like `select g, count(g) from (select unnest(genres) from artists) dt(g) group by g` would be cleaner (assuming the column is `text[]` rather than `jsonb` of course). For a `jsonb` column, you might want to look at the `json_array_elements_text` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely trivial task if you just use a decent relational db design:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :artist_genres
end

class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_genres
  has_many :artists, through: :artist_genres
end

class ArtistGenre < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist 
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

You could then get the result by:

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :artist_genres

  # This will instanciate a record for each row just like your average scope
  # and return a ActiveRecord::Relation object.
  def self.with_artist_counts
    self.joins(:artist_genres)
        .select('genres.name, COUNT(artist_genres.id) AS artists_count')
        .group(:id)
  end

  # This pulls the columns as raw sql results and creates a hash with the genre 
  # name as keys
  def self.pluck_artist_counts
    self.connection.select_all(with_artist_counts.to_sql).inject({}) do |hash, row|
      hash.merge(row["name"] => row["artists_count"])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What might not be trivial is overhauling a DB that he did not build but is stuck working with.

Comment: True @Beartech, but its still within the realm of doable unless its a hopeless situation where the client refuses to allow any alterations to the db schema. And defintatly worth it if this feature is important.